# Referencing Knowledge base in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 system that run jenkins.I have created a knowledge base(build failure analyzer) in jenkins that runs on System1.I wanted to know whether I can use the same knowledge base on System2 because I am having the similar set of jobs in both the system.Please do help me if it is possible if I can use the knowledge base on other system.